# backend error when put file with python connector

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

with the connector python, the sql query work fine. However, when i use an instruction (put file file:///localfile), i have an error:

> TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'backend'

With snowSql on the same Server, it's work.

the code used:

```
import snowflake.connector
ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(
        user='lincavo',
        account='*****',
        password='*******',
        database='DEV_POC_VELOS_DB',
        schema='DATALAB',
        role='dev_data_analyst'
        )

cur = ctx.cursor()
FILE_NAME = "/home/lincoln/DEV/snowflake/100003097-SC.json"

sql="PUT file:///home/lincoln/DEV/snowflake/100003097-SC.json @local_velos_json  auto_compress=false"
cur.execute(sql)
```

snowflake-connector-python 2.6.2

can you help me please ?
thanks

Comment: you need to provide your code

Comment: i have tried with snowsql on the same server and it's work.

Comment: i have resolved the issue to update package (2.6.2 -> 2.7.0)

Comment: Hi @antoinevokleber, any solution for this? I am getting same error for GET command. Are we not supposed to use these commands in execute() ?